# can't login via 'root and ssh keys' after adding non-root user

Tags: 20.04, root, useradd

Ubuntu 20.04 server (on a Digital Ocean droplet) here.

I had set up root login with SSH keys, and login password disabled.

Everything worked fine.

The other day I decided to add a non-root user (because it's generally probably not a good idea to do everything as a root user).

So, I used the `useradd` command to add a new user. And copied over my `.ssh` folder from the root's home directory to this new user's home directory.

Result:

- I can no longer login via root (with SSH keys).
- I can't login via the newly added user (this I understand because I didn't do `chown` to give the new user ownership over the `.ssh` folder)

I am now locked out of my server. Not a biggie because it's a test server, and I'll use the DigitalOcean terminal to reinstall everything from scratch.

**My question for you** regarding why I can't login via root (with SSH keys): What did I do wrong?

puTTY log:

> login as: root

> Server refused our key

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Comment: It might be helpful to add diagnostic output from your connection attempt (`ssh -v ...`, add more `v`s as you feel appropriate).

Comment: @steeldriver : thanks for the suggestion. I've put some log info in my post. I didn't want to put the entire SSH log output because it's very very long, but if needed I can post that too.